# Algorithm, blocks not closed

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I am sure this is looks ugly but it got the job done for what I wanted it to look like aesthetically. The error I am getting is that some blocks are not closed, but I am not sure how to correct it.

Here is my latex:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{LSM Algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Generate $M$ paths of stock prices $S_i(t)$, $i = 1,\ldots,M$
\State which evolves in discreet time index $j = 1,\ldots, N$ (time interval $\Delta t = \frac{T}{N}$)
\For{$i$}
    \For{$j$}
      \State Generate $S_{i} = S_{i-1}e^{(r-q-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})\Delta t + \sigma\sqrt{\Delta t}Z_{i,j}}, Z_{i,j}\sim N(0,1)$
\EndFor
\EndFor
 \ \ \ \textbf{end for}\\
\textbf{end for}
\State Put $P_i \gets f(S_{i}(t_N))$ for all $i$
\For{$t$ from $t_{N-1}$ to $t_1$}\\
 \ \ \ Find in the money paths $\{i_1,i_2,\ldots, i_n\}$ such that $f(S_i(t)) > 0$\\
 \ \ \ Set $ipaths \gets \{i_1,i_2,\ldots, i_n\}$\\
 \ \ \ Set $x_i\gets S_i(t)$ and $y_i\gets e^{-r\Delta t}P_i$ for $i\in ipaths$\\
 \ \ \ Apply regression on $x,y$ to obtain regression coefficients $\hat{\beta}_0,\ldots, \hat{\beta}_k$\\
 \ \ \ Estimate continuation values $\hat{C}(S_i(t))$ then calculate the value of immediate exercise $f(S_i(t))$\\ \ \ \ for $i\in ipaths$
\For{$i$}
\If{$i\in ipaths$ \textbf{and} $f(S_i(t)) > \hat{C}(S_i(t))$ }
\State $P_i\gets f(S_i(t))$\\
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \textbf{else}\\
\State $P_i\gets e^{-r\Delta t}P_i$\\
\EndIf
\EndFor
 \ \ \ \textbf{end if}\\
\ \ \ \textbf{end for}\\
 \textbf{end for}\\
$price\gets \frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^{M}e^{-r\Delta t}P_i$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an `\EndFor`, that's why the error message.

In any case, your code *is* really ugly, I would say a mess...

Probably, the following code is what you are after.

Please note how `\MyFor` and `\EndMyFor` are used to obtain a `for` without `do`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}{MyFor}{EndMyFor}[1]{%
  \textbf{for} #1}{%
  \textbf{end for}}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{LSM Algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Generate $M$ paths of stock prices $S_i(t)$, $i = 1,\ldots,M$
\State which evolves in discreet time index $j = 1,\ldots, N$ (time interval $\Delta t = \frac{T}{N}$)
\For{$i$}
    \For{$j$}
      \State Generate $S_{i} = S_{i-1}e^{(r-q-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})\Delta t + \sigma\sqrt{\Delta t}Z_{i,j}}, Z_{i,j}\sim N(0,1)$
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\State Put $P_i \gets f(S_{i}(t_N))$ for all $i$
\For{$t$ from $t_{N-1}$ to $t_1$}
    \State Find in the money paths $\{i_1,i_2,\ldots, i_n\}$ such that $f(S_i(t)) > 0$
    \State Set $ipaths \gets \{i_1,i_2,\ldots, i_n\}$
    \State Set $x_i\gets S_i(t)$ and $y_i\gets e^{-r\Delta t}P_i$ for $i\in ipaths$
    \State Apply regression on $x,y$ to obtain regression coefficients $\hat{\beta}_0,\ldots, \hat{\beta}_k$
    \State Estimate continuation values $\hat{C}(S_i(t))$ then calculate the value of immediate exercise $f(S_i(t))$
    \MyFor{$i\in ipaths$}
    \For{$i$}
    \If{$i\in ipaths$ \textbf{and} $f(S_i(t)) > \hat{C}(S_i(t))$}
        \State $P_i\gets f(S_i(t))$
    \Else
        \State $P_i\gets e^{-r\Delta t}P_i$
    \EndIf
    \EndFor
\EndMyFor
\EndFor
\State $price\gets \frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^{M}e^{-r\Delta t}P_i$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]